# Formula for looking up and filtering data from a sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to do a complex formula using google sheets:

I have a list of place that will be visited by different people.
Some places are not to be visited, marked with /
Some places need to be assigned, marked with ?

Wanted outcome:

A list of cells that changes every day automatic.
An overview of who is going where that day and what needs to be assigned.

So I need a formula that can select a row based on today() and then filter out Persons in that row. Then for each person, another formula that looks up the first row in the table and puts duplicates together.

Example:

[image: Data]

Wanted outcome:

[image: wanted result]

Link to excel file, but it needs to work in google sheets too: [xlsx](https://ufile.io/oknvwjid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is not the most elegant but it does the job.

First I build a column with date and unique persons or ? in this column:

```
=unique(sort(transpose(index(A1:H10,match(today(),A1:A10,0)))))
```

[image]

Then I find Places corresponding to these persons (I use filter function for it and then I use textjoin to keep them in single cell).
The formula is copied down as filter function does not accept a range and arrayformula as a filtering criterium.

[image]

My solution is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GTy_UaFP8LbA8OLnEhT_R_twpDCIWCuvQfBAigqtbR0/copy

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. Great insight for me into the formula's you used. I added a filter around the unique formula to filter out the "/"